# how can I control the second internal clock

Tags: alarm, clock, clock-speed

My alarm clock app has been occasionally failing to ring in the morning, but I don't believe the problem is due to the app.

In other news I recently added a lock screen app that happens to display the time in two locations on the screen (one from app itself and other my widget) and on days when the alarm fails to ring I noticed that the second clock just stops, (which today says 3:52 am)

I have been checking the two clocks before bed, but last night when I checked it was good, yet the alarm failed this morning and now the times are different

I presume there are two internal clocks and the lock screen and alarm app are both using the problem clock, which is probably being killed by some task killer.

I can't afford to oversleep again!

Have Note 3 with latest android update
Any ideas?

Comment: "some task killer": do you have a task killer installed? If so, uninstall it!

Comment: +1 to that – especially if it's one of those "auto-RAM-optimizers" using Chuck-Norris-Roundhouse-Kicks to "clean up stuff". Those almost always backfire more than proving useful.